# Animated ListView.builder, so that selected item is added to a stack and the rest of the ListView translates to the left

Tags: listview, flutter, animation

I'm working on a flutter app where I'm using a listview.builder. When I select a listtile within the listview.builder, I want to animate it such that the selected item is recreated on top of the listview.builder in a stack, ensuring that the stack is positioned the same as the location of the list tile in the listview.builder. Is this possible, if so any ideas.

Comment: It's definitely possible. You can use a `Stack` within each list tile, which would be a better idea than putting a stack over the whole `ListView`.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try implementing it this way instead.